# Getting the color of a movie clip under a tracking point

Tags: video-sequence-editor, tracking

I'd like to fix a movie clip to have constant exposure all over. Instead of fixing it manually I'd like to set a tracking point for an object and use the color information under the tracker to drive the color correction clip modifier, i.e. to make sure the brightness of said object is always constant.

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the color directly under a Tracker like this

[image]

Comment: oops i didn't see the vse tag

Comment: Compositor works too I presume. Will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Since no other answer appeared and it sort of solves the problem, I will mark it as accepted.